# Is there a (lower) limit/minimum for learning rate values?

Tags: optimization, loss-functions, train

I'm building a model for traffic prediction with ConvLSTM and A3T-GCN cells. Since the input data is highly complex and the model is relatively big, I can only load `batch_size=2` on my model. This makes my epoch be divided into `17 000` batches, which seems to be a lot. I've been observing that my training loss is going down, and then up/sideways with high noise, indicating that my learning rate might be too high.

The problem is: my learning rate is already `5e-5` and I'm using StepLR with `gamma=0.5`. I've read that `lr` shouldn't be smaller than `1e-6`, but how strict is that?

Comment: Consider accumulating gradients instead of using a smaller batch size

Comment: @Firebug thanks for the suggestion. I can implement the accumulating gradients, but that wouldn't allow me to have a bigger batch size, as my tensors do not fit the GPU VRAM for `batch_size > 2`

Comment: It is literally a way to increase batch size without having to keep the samples and gradients in memory

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict rule prohibiting the use of smaller than usual learning rates. Training neural networks is an experimental discipline. You need to test experimentally what works. If you suspect from experiments you've made, that further decreasing the learning rate is worth a try, do try it out and observe the result.